# missing go type for returned values

Tags: go, types, return-value, auto

How come no warnings are issued for the following code?

```
$ cat ret.go
package main
import "fmt"
func foobar(x int, y int) (z, w int) {
    if x+y > 100 {
         _,w = 3,5
    } else {
        _,w = "MMM",9
    }
    return z,w
}

func main() {
    var x int
    _,x = foobar(42,13)
    fmt.Println(x)
}
$ go build -gcflags=-l ret.go
```

For the least, the go compiler should know the size of `z` right?

Comment: The z is initialized by default value which is 0. You can find more about default values here https://tour.golang.org/basics/12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In golang, you can define multiple variable in one line like next:

```
var identifier1, identifier2 type
```

So, `z, w` here both declared as `int`.

Additional, see [this](https://www.golangprograms.com/the-return-values-of-a-function-can-be-named-in-golang.html):

> The return values of a function can be named in Golang

Then, if you not assign a value to `z`, it will has a default value of `int`, that is `0`. So, no warning, the code is ok.